# Промис вызывает следующий then когда предыдущий ничего не возвращает

Tags: javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему происходит вызов промиса, который следует после промиса функции user.get, если последний ничего не возвращает?

```js
var user = {
  get: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });
  },
  set: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
    });
  }
};

user.get().then(function() {
  console.log(new Date(), "get");
}).then(function() {
  console.log(new Date(), "set");
});
```

Comment: У промиса можно вызывать сколько угодно then

Comment: @НазарКалитюк и? следующий вызывается только если предыдущий что-то возвращает через return

Comment: @ikerya функция в JS **всегда** что-то возвращает. В данном случае значение `undefined`

Comment: Впрочем тут вам стоит ещё раз прочитать как работают промисы

Comment: @AlexeyTen http://prntscr.com/ipmn39 -- написано, что следующий then вызывается только при условии, что предыдущий возвратил промис

Comment: Я не знаю что это за текст, но это очень странно (либо тут сильно не хватает контекста)

Comment: @AlexeyTen https://learn.javascript.ru/promise#%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74334/discussion-between-ikerya-and-alexey-ten).

Comment: Там речь идёт про ещё один setTimeout (т.е. асинхронный вызов) и что бы получить его результат нужно создать и вернуть промис. Тем не менее then всё равно всегда возвращает промис, если нет явного вызова return, то это будет заресолвленый undefined